# Birationally equivalent elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

I encountered a question about showing that the curve
$$
y^2 = x^4 + a_3 x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0, \qquad\qquad(1)
$$
where $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$, can be birationally transformed over $\mathbb{Q}$ to a curve of the form
$$
y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B \qquad \qquad (2)
$$
where $A, B \in \mathbb{Z}$. The hint was to write equation (1) in the form $y^2 = g(x)^2 + h(x)$, where $g(x)$ is quadratic and $h(x)$ is linear, and then transforming using $T = y+g(x), S=x(y+g(x))$.

This was fine. I was then asked to execute this procedure on the curve $y^2 = 2x^2 + 9$, by first converting it into the form of (1) (i.e. making it monic). After some work I was able to transform it into
$$
y^2 = x^3 + 5832 x,
$$
which, as you can see, is now in the form of equation (2) (perhaps someone can check this is correct).

The final part was to show that $y^2 = 2x^4 + 7$ can "also be birationally transformed over $\mathbb{Q}$ to the same form". It was tough to see how to do this at first. But I used the transformation that replaces $x$ by $x+1$, giving the constant term $9$ in the polynomial, and tried to follow the same method as above. However, it quickly becomes *very* messy. Is this the right way to go about doing it? Or is there some slick deduction from the first part I am missing?

Comment: Yep. Think about scaling $y$ and $x$ by constants.

Answer (score 2):

Let me offer a couple of references for this:

- Page 77, L. Mordell, *Diophantine Equations*, Academic Press, New York, 1969
- Section 2.5.3 (p. 37), L. Washington, *Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography*, Chapman & Hall, 2003.

The results that I refer to are quoted in Appendix B of [my paper with Steve Miller and Scott Arms](http://alozano.clas.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/490/2014/01/constrECrank_ALM.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @PPenguin I just fixed the link.